# Authorization issue while trying to access the adls gen 2 files through pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-pipelines, azure-synapse

I am trying to run my spark pool notebook using pipeline in azure synpase. THe notebook reads files from my ADLS Gen2. But when I am running the pipeline I am facing this issue:
"This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.", 403, GET, file_name.parquet?timeout=90, AuthorizationPermissionMismatch, "This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.

{"error":{"code":"AuthenticationFailed","message":"Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.

Comment: Could you include the roles that you currently have?

Comment: @SrideviMachavarapu-MT owner access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to give the role access to workspace as well in the subscription access control (IAM). It is working now.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you typically access your storage accounts from Synapse: Your authorizations/permissions and the Synapse Managed Identity's

Whichever identity (yours or the MI) intended to run the notebook and access your data lake must have **Storage Blob Data Contributor** access in your storage account's IAM section or you'll get that error.

If your managed identity has the role and you still get the error, make sure your notebook is running as the managed identity and not as you:

[image: Run Notebook as managed identity]

---

[image: Notebook indicating it's using a managed identity]